# How can I prevent Flask API server shutdown upon large message requests?

Tags: python, flask

My Flask app supports a multi-classification API for bulk messages.

As part of performance testing, I made requests for 100 / 1,000 / 10,000 messages at once.

However, an issue arises during the bulk processing of 10,000 messages, causing the API server to crash:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without response"))

[image]

Below is a rough code structure.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


def bulk_inference(messages, batch_size=100):
    batches = [messages[i:i + batch_size]
               for i in range(0, len(messages), batch_size)]
    
    res = []
    for batch in batches:
        res.append(model(batch))

    return res

@app.route('/bulk_clf')
def bulk_clf():
    messages = [i['message'] for i in request.json['bulk']]
     
    #####################################################  
    # Request and Messages saving code in PostgreSQL DB #
    #####################################################

    res = bulk_inference(messages)

    #######################################################  
    # Classification Results saving code in PostgreSQL DB #
    #######################################################

    return res


if __name__ = "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

I tried inserting `time.sleep(0.2)` between batches of messages, but it didn't resolve the issue.
I also checked `app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']`, and it was set to `None`.
I want a robust API server that can handle requests for more than 10,000 messages effectively.